# Apache reverse proxy config always returning same site

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, reverse-proxy

Situation: ubuntu server 14.04 with apache and bugzilla installed on a dedicated vm.
Everything works well, on bugzilla.myexternal.com, bugzilla.myinternal.xyz and on LAN IP address

Now I want to make other internal servers available on the same external IP, by host name based forwarding, with the same apache instance. DNS records added and resolving correctly for other1.myexternal.com, other2.myexternal.com, etc

(internal DNS already covers/resolves internal names of otherX to local ip addresses for internal use)

After reading through the atricles here and on apache, I thinck I was able to distill  the bugzila site-conf and add the other site-conf as intended. However, there are so many contradicting articles with different 'solutions', and in the end I can't make it work. Whatever host is called, I always end up with the initial bugzila site. When I a2dissite bugzilla, then I always get forwarded to the first reverse proxy site (showing that the proxying actually works)

Here is what the site-conf looks like.

bugzilla:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName bugzilla.myexternal.com
   ServerAlias 192.168.aaa.bbb

   DocumentRoot /var/www/html
   <Directory /var/www/html>
      AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
      Options +ExecCGI
      DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
      AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

other1: (and similar for otherX, all having static internal ip)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ServerName other1.myexternal.com

#   ProxyRequests off ->also tried without commenting out
   ProxyPass / http://192.168.aaa.ccc/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.aaa.ccc/
</VirtualHost>
```

apache reload without errors/warnings.

When looking with  'apache2ctl -S' I see that they are loaded correctly. But in all cases (when disabling certain virtual hosts), the site that gets shown is always the default server mentionned by ' apache2ctl -S':

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server bugzilla.myexternal.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bugzilla2.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost bugzilla.myexternal.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/bugzilla2.conf:1)
             alias 192.168.aaa.bbb
     port 80 namevhost other1.myexternal.com (/etc/apache2/sites-    enabled/comfoway.conf:2)
     port 80 namevhost other2.myexternal.com (/etc/apache2/sites-    enabled/spcway.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
Define: MODPERL2
Define: ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Question: what to do to make this work and not always show the default server?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, and I'm embarrased to say, but it's down to prescribing the wrong domain and TLD for the other serverNames. We have several doamin names with only different TLD that I mixed up. But they do resolve, due to how our DNS is set up with CNAME records.

As a result, no matching serverName is found by apache and the default is shown.

The good news is (for other users) that the above configuration works, so if you need a reverse proxy and local server combination on this unubtu and apache 2.4, then this is the way forward.

regards,
Christof